# Taking the inverse Laplace Transform as a vector operation

Tags: vector, integral-transforms

I am solving a system of first-order equations using matrix operations and the Laplace Transform. I begin with the matrix equation that represents the solution to my system, like this:

$$ \underline{\underline{\mathbf{m}}} \mathcal{L} { \mathbf{N}(t) } = \mathbf{N_0}$$

Bold symbols are vectors (functions) and double-underlined symbols are matrix. $\mathcal{L}$ is the Laplace Transform.

To make this computation I first write and invert the matrix $\underline{\underline{m}}$.

```
m[s_, l1_, l2_] := {{s + l1, 0}, {-l1, s + l2}}
invm[s_, l1_, l2_] := Inverse[m[s, l1, l2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I can input the initial conditions:

```
Subscript[N, 0] = {1, 0}
```

Then I use the inverse to get the Laplace transform of the (vector) solution:

```
R0[s_, l1_, l2_] := invm[s, l1, l2] . Subscript[N, 0]
```

Then, the final solution is simply an inverse Laplace Transform of this resulting vector, so I attempt:

```
N[t_, l1_, l2_] := Simplify[InverseLaplaceTransform[R0[s, l1, l2], s, t]]
```

But this command results in the error:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can I get the inverse Laplace Transform to work on a vector in order to simplify my notation going forward?

Comment: **Subscript[N, 0] = {1, 0}** Do not use [N](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html)  as variable name, this is a function name in Mathematica. _gives the numerical value of expr._  Try with another lower case letter and see if this fixes the issue you are having. Also, I would avoid  using `Subscript` in Mathematica myself. The less fancy letters you use, the less problems you will have. You can use indexed variables instead if you must.

Comment: And the actual error is coming from your call `N[t_, l1_, l2_]`  . Again `N` is builtin function. Try `n[t_, l1_, l2_]` and also remove the use of the other `N` you had before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand your use of `Subscript[N, 0] = {1, 0}` actually and what it is for? So  I might be overlooking something here. But why not just

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
m[s_Symbol,l1_,l2_]:={{s+l1,0},{-l1,s+l2}}
invm[s_Symbol,l1_,l2_]:=Inverse[m[s,l1,l2]]
R0[s_Symbol,l1_,l2_]:=invm[s,l1,l2].{1,0}
n[t_Symbol,l1_,l2_,s_Symbol]:=Simplify[InverseLaplaceTransform[R0[s,l1,l2],s,t]]
n[t,2,3,s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would pass all the symbols involved, this includes $t$ and also $s$. Avoid using global symbols as they could be assigned to some values in your notebook.

Comment: Well the `Subscript[N,0] = {1,0}` was just because the notation made sense, no particular reason. I didn't know `N[]` was protected, so that is the answer.